# Sed Usage With Remembered Portions

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix

Lets say I have an image in the format `img_12-31-06_99.jpg`

Now I am trying to move the `'.jpg'` to the front of the expression to get

```
`.jpgimg_12-31-06_99`
```

So I tried matching the first portion of the expression with `img_[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*_[0-9]*`

then `.jpg` to match the remainder. I used `\2` to move the 2nd portion to the front and `\1` to move the first expression caught to the end.

```
echo img_12-31-06_99.jpg | sed 's/\(img_[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*_[0-9]*\) \(.jpg\)/\2 \1/'
```

Now this returns my original expression :

```
img_12-31-06_99.jpg
```

Can anyone explain to to me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, you have a problematic space in both the regex and the replacement, the following should work:

```
sed 's/\(img_[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*_[0-9]*\)\(.jpg\)/\2\1/'
```

For example:

```
$ echo img_12-31-06_99.jpg | sed 's/\(img_[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*_[0-9]*\)\(.jpg\)/\2\1/'
.jpgimg_12-31-06_99
```

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for. Could I possibly ask why the space was causing sed to have no effect on the initial filename?

Comment: The space made it so the file name did not match the regex, and `s///` in sed will only modify matched lines.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could I possible ask another question when you match an expression using a regex like "[0-9]+.jpg" how do you only return the [0-9] portion? I tried googling this but I'm not familiar with what this process is called, but I know I have done it before.

Comment: If you are using sed you would want to do something like `s/\([0-9]\+\)\.jpg/\1/`, this would replace match with just the digits.  For regex in general, you can either capture the digits or use a lookahead to match the `.jpg`, so that it isn't actually a part of the match.  The regex here would look like `[0-9]+(?=\.jpg)`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I guess I didn't fully understand what my original sed statement was doing. Thank you again.